# Why is this rule location-dependent in this Makefile? really strange

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have this test Makefile that runs ok. It makes three symbolic links and just echoes the link names(This just symbolizing compile procedure).

```
ARCH = o-optimize
PGM = $(ARCH)/sieve.exe

all: ${ARCH} $(PGM)

$(ARCH):
    test -d ${ARCH} || mkdir $(ARCH)

$(PGM): $(XXX)
    echo gathering $(XXX)

clean:
    rm -fr $(ARCH)
    rm -f $(XXX)

XXX = init.c system.h config.h

$(XXX) :
    ln -s ../src/$@  $@
```

Here is the result.

```
ckim@stph45:~/test] make clean
rm -fr o-optimize
rm -f init.c system.h config.h
ckim@stph45:~/test] make
test -d o-optimize || mkdir o-optimize
echo gathering init.c system.h config.h
gathering init.c system.h config.h
```

But if I move the XXX definition and and symbolic link generation rule to the top, it doesn't work. Changed Makefile :

```
XXX = init.c system.h config.h

$(XXX) :
    ln -s ../src/$@  $@

ARCH = o-optimize
PGM = $(ARCH)/sieve.exe

all: ${ARCH} $(PGM)

$(ARCH):
    test -d ${ARCH} || mkdir $(ARCH)

$(PGM): $(XXX)
    echo gathering $(XXX)

clean:
    rm -fr $(ARCH)
    rm -f $(XXX)
```

And the result :

```
ckim@stph45:~/test] make clean
rm -fr o-optimize
rm -f init.c system.h config.h
ckim@stph45:~/test] make
ln -s ../src/init.c  init.c
```

Why does the XXX definition and rule location matter? XXX represents three file names but only the first file's symbolic link is being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_4.html) explains:

> The order of rules is not significant, except for determining the
>   **default goal**: the target for `make` to consider, if you do not otherwise specify one. The default goal is the target of the first
>   rule in the first makefile.

In other words, `$(XXX)` is being considered as the default goal, not `all`. The rest of your makefile is not even running.

There are two ways around this:

1. Explicitly specify the target: `make all`
2. Use `.DEFAULT_GOAL`:

   .DEFAULT_GOAL := all

Comment: Ok, that was correct. (actually I was aware of the rule, but missed that point). But the bigger problem in my case is why is the symbolic link generation recipe making the first symbolic link and not all three links?